# Swift json decode with dynamic keys

Tags: json, swift, decoder

i'm trying to decode a nested json with dynamic keys, but can't find a solution.
here's my json:

```
{
    "available_channels": {
        "1000": {
            "creation_date": "1111222",
            "category_id": "9"
        },
        "1001": {
            "creation_date": "222333",
            "category_id": "10"
        }
}
```

as you can see, "1000" and "1001" are dynamique.

The models i'm using:

```
struct StreamsData: Codable{
    let availableChannels: AvailableChannels
}

struct AvailableChannels: Codable{
    let channels: [String: Channel]
}

struct Channel: Codable{
    let creationDate: String
    let categoryId: String
}
```

'StreamsData' is the root object

'AvailableChannels' is the objects containing all channels objects

'Channel' channel model

decoding the json:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
let streams = try decoder.decode(StreamsData.self, from: data)
```

With this code i have this error:

> CodingKeys(stringValue: "availableChannels", intValue: nil)
>   - debugDescription : "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"channels\", intValue: nil) (\"channels\")."

The problem is clear, as 'AvailableChannels' is declared to have a 'channel' property, the decoder is trying to find "channels" as key for the object containing the "creation_date".

Could you help me to solve this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need

```
struct StreamsData: Codable{
    let availableChannels: [String: Channel]
}

struct Channel: Codable{
    let creationDate,categoryId: String 
}
```

---

```
do {
    let dec = JSONDecoder()
    dec.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let res = try dec.decode(StreamsData.self, from: data)
}
catch { 
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: lol ! i just found this 1 min after posting this !! but thank you :)

Comment: Why do we need to provide strategy `convertFromSnakeCase` ?